# Filters in SSMS2012

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssms-2012

This is not a technical question

All I want is to know whether there is a filter option in SQL Management Studio. Which can be used to query through the tables and records without user typing the whole query in query editor

I had seen the same in Toad where we can filter any data very fastly even without the knowledge of sql query.

I had goggled it but found nothing

Comment: Are you looking for a `view`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a filter option in the SSMS almost same as that of the TOOD .
Steps for filtering table data in SQL Mangagement studio ares

First right click the table and select Edit 200 rows( number of rows may differ asper your settings)

Then Go to  Query Designer Toolbar (mark it visible from VIEW>>>Toolbar if its not visible)

There is a button Show Criteria Pane(ctrl

we can use the filter column in this pane for filtering records based on the in put

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is not available in SSMS.